# Rewrite and redirect with php variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am simply trying to rewrite automatically this:

**From:** `mysite.com/channel.php?id=BBC&name=British Broadcasting Company &date=today`

**To:** `mysite.com/channel-britishbroadcastingcompany-today.html`

**I've tried with:**

```
RewriteRule ^channel-(.*)-(.*)\.html$ /channel.php?id=1&name=$2&date=$3 [R]
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: What do you mean with "nothing happens"?

Comment: there is no redirect

Comment: I cannot confirm this. Using your rule shows the wrong parameters of course, but in my test environment it works apart from that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope this simplest one will help you out. This will redirect if

> **1.** `REQUEST_URI` is `/channel.php`
>
> **2.** `QUERY_STRING` matches this pattern `id=something&name=something&date=something`

Redirect this to `/channel-%1-%2.html` here

> **1.** `%1` will hold value of `name` parameter
>
> **2.** `%2` will hold value of `date` parameter

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/channel\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=.*?&name=(.*?)&date=(.*)
RewriteRule .* /channel-%1-%2.html? [R=301]
```

As per the requirement specified by OP to first `redirect` url on `html page` on the basis of some `query parameters` then rewriting the request on `previous page`. So the complete code of .htaccess will be like this.

```
RewriteEngine on
Options -MultiViews

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/channel\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=.*?&name=(.*?)&date=(.*)
RewriteRule .* /channel-%1-%2? [R=301]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/channel\-(.*?)\-(.*?)
RewriteRule .* /channel.php? [L]
```

Explanation of 2nd part which is added.

> **1.** `REQUEST_FILENAME` if file does not exist as a file and directory.
>
> **2.** `REQUEST_URI` If request_uri starts with such pattern `channel-somewords-somewords`

then rewrite request on `/channel.php`

Comment: @user2490424 sorry it was 12:00 according to gmt +5 30 thats why i was not able to reply, can you tell you are getting 404 for which file, so is your that html file on which you are redirecting exists?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain myself properly. I want both rewrite and redirect. Do you think this would be ok? `RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /channel\.php\?name=(.*)&data=(.*)\ HTTP RewriteRule ^channel.php /channel/%2/%3? [R,L] #Internal rewrite RewriteRule ^channel/(.*)/(.*)$ /channel.php?name=$1&data=$2 [L]`

Comment: @user2490424 I dont think it is good way, I have to test it further, but my .htaccess will work fine. for sure

Comment: with yours .htacces i get 404 error for `channel-bbc-today.html`, `channel-bbc-tomorrow.html` etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144338/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-user2490424).

Comment: @user2490424  I have updated my post, you can check and for further requirement you can just let me know.

Comment: Thanks, what if i don't want .html to be in the url anymore? I tried with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} channel-(.*)-(.*)$` but of course it's not working.

Comment: Do you want to remove `.html` as well?

Comment: Exactly. Also i just tried your code and it looks like channel.php is getting empty values, but maybe there is something wrong with my cache.

Comment: First of all, thank you. It's not working, channel.php gets empty parameters. I think what is wrong is the last line cause it should be pass parameters again to channel.php

Comment: @user2490424 we can discuss over chat i will let you know how you can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the problem correctly, You currently have a file **channel.php** and what You want to achieve is get more "friendly" URLs for SEO and general aesthetics in the browser location bar but still have channel.php handle your requests.

If this is really the case then You need a **two-way** rewrite.
First, You need to take your original URL and redirect it to a new, pretty version.
Second, You need to rewrite this pretty URI internally and still feed it to channel.php behind the scenes.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# This part rewrites channel.php?name=X&date=Y into channel-X-Y.html
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} =GET
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*\&)?name=([^&]+)\&date=([^&]+)(?:\&(.*))?
RewriteRule ^channel.php$ channel-%2-%3.html?%1%4 [R,L,NE]

# This part rewrites it back into channel.php but keeps the "friendly" URL visible
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^channel-(.*)-(.*).html$ channel.php?name=$1&date=$2 [L,QSA]
```

- Note that the first rule-set limits the rewrite to method GET - otherwise You will lose any submitted POST data.
- It also allows for any other query-string parameters to surround *name* and *date* (the rest of query-string parameters will pass-through to .html URI and then will be picked back up by channel.php)
- Also note the *ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS* rule - this is crucial, without that part You'll be stuck in redirect loop.

Comment: It works! But can you please explain the difference between yours .htacces and this one:   `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /channel\.php\?name=(.*)&data=(.*)\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^channel.php /channel/%2/%3? [R,L]

#Internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^channel/(.*)/(.*)$ /channel.php?name=$1&data=$2 [L]`

Comment: Basically this is a different approach to the same thing except it tries to match the whole thing in one liner vs the complete request, and I did 3 separate RewriteCond conditions instead, which gives more granular control. Your example can't check in the same line for environment for example. Also, if You decide to go for `channel/*` - You should also be aware of possible collision with channel.php if `MultiViews` is on

Comment: Thanks. I made some improvements on my site and now channel.php get only two parameters. So i edited your code in this way: (is it ok?) `RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/channel\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} name=(.*?)&date=(.*)
RewriteRule .* /channel-%1-%2? [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^channel-(.*)-(.*)$ /channel.php?name=$1&date=$2 [L]`

Comment: Looks good. Did You try it? My example may be a bit overcomplicated indeed as it accounts for other parameters that may or may not be present in the original URL prior to rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

See

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9-_.]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1&goto=$2 [NC,L]
```

What it's going to do is check the index.php and replace to some like, `site/dir/index.php` to `site/dir/namehere` than in index.php you can use explode() to separate the values of current url ang get the variables

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are asking for rewrite although you are using redirect flag in your current rules, and also assuming BBC to be static in id variable then try with below,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^channel-([^/]+)-([^/]+).html$ channel.php?id=BBC&name=$1&date=$2 [L]
```